# is_page Funtion for Posts ?

Tags: posts, functions, pages

I am using a plugin [Bottom of every post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bottom-of-every-post/)

which have a a function `if( !is_page( ) && file_exists( $fileName )){`

which is printing custom Text on bottom of every pages, i want to show them on **pages not on the posts**, can anyone suggest me a function or a way to complete this job ?

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ! before `is_page()`.

The function `is_page()` is built into WordPress and only tests if the post being viewed is a page or not. The `!` stands for "not", so if you take it out, the code will only return true on that part if it is a page.

Comment: I showed that i am a noob ha ha, thank you very much.

Comment: A good place to look up WordPress related functions is in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hack somebody else's plugin, which will require additional work every time the plugin is updated, why not use a simple filter on `the_content`?

```
function bottom_of_post_wpse_166623($content) {
  if (is_page()) {
    $extra_content = 'abcdefg';
    return $content.$extra_content;
  }
}
add_filter('the_content','bottom_of_post_wpse_166623');
```

You can add that code to your theme, or to a plugin of your own ([which basically what the plugin you reference does](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/bottom-of-every-post/trunk/bottom_of_every_post.php#L55)).